# How to avoid voicemail interaction in a outbound call?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We have a code that connects two target numbers in a conference to talk to each other.

We make two outbound calls, directing both to a unique conference via twiml.
Our logic is perfect when both of them answers or when one of the outbound calls gives up on ringing returning a webhook in a 'no-answer' status.

The problem is when the person rejects the call. In that case, the voicemail triggers the conference start, like if it was answered. It connects the voicemail with a person.

We need a way to stop this from happening or to identify a true human answer from an voicemail one. It is generating empty recordings, confusing the callers and in a not answered call we are sending an SMS, explaining who was trying to communicate. We need to identify all unsuccessful calls for that.

Anybody has a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are looking for [answering machine detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection). Or, alternatively, you can use [call screening as described on this page](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132567-Can-Twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine-).